# Do iframes store anything in a mobile app's temporary data?

Tags: android, iphone, iframe, mobile

I'm currently making a mobile app that displays PDFs for users on a screen using iframes. For legal reasons, it is EXTREMELY important that these files are not stored on the device once the user is done viewing them, either in memory or a temp cache. I'm almost certain this isn't the case, but I want to make sure - do mobile or tablet apps store anything in the app cache when loading content from an iframe? Is there a way to verify this? Thank you.

I've tried implementing this in an app and checking the cache manually, which is why I don't think it's the case, but I don't have a ton of mobile experience and this particular bit is very important so I want to make sure.

Comment: Pretty much any browser caches every file it downloads to display by default.  But to know more we'd need to know what browser you're using-  there's more than one on Android.  Or if you're using a WebView in a native app displaying HTML-  in that case you have more cache control.

Comment: @GabeSechan The webview is a good idea, I could implement it with a Cache-Control: max-age=0 and that would probably solve my issue.